# How to integrate a rational function whose numerator and denominator are first order and second order polynomials?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I know that

$$\int \frac{x-a}{x(1-x)}dx = -[a\ln x+ (1-a) \ln(1-x)]+const$$

but how can I prove it?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Would be good if the downvoter tells me where my question flaws so that I can possibly improve it, instead of downvoting apparently randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$\frac{x-a}{x(1-x)}=\frac Ax + \frac B{1-x}$$

At $x=0$, $A = \frac{-a}{1} = -a$

At $x=1$, $B = \frac{1-a}{1} = 1-a$

So we have $$\frac{-a}{x} + \frac{1-a}{1-x}$$

Could you proceed further?

Comment: Jus one thing: you deliberately substitute the values of x for which the expressions are indeterminate  because they are the zeros of the denominators.it seems to me u mean this to be a limit to infinity rather than a pure substitution of a value And it seems that u do this so that one quantity becomes very big as the den approaches to zero and so the other can be discarded:is that so? Is it a common technique? Does it have a name or is it just so?

Comment: @FrancescoBoi You can just cross multiply and find that $x-a = A(1-x) +Bx$. So at $x=0$, $Bx = 0$ and we have $0-a = A(1-0) \Rightarrow A =-a$. Similarly we can find for $x=1$. And the method I've used is commonly called **Cover up method**, which is similar to the cross multiplication process, but it just works a bit faster. Here are some links : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgPviiv_oZs , https://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Advanced%20Level/Cover%20up%20rule.htm